# Display all managers and employees without a manager

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, self-join, correlated-subquery

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 that for explanation purposes contains, ID, Employee and ManagerID.

eg:

```
ID  Employee  ManagerID
1   A        NULL
2   B        2
3   C        2
```

I want to write a query that returns all non related `ManagerID`'s and `ID`'s where `ManagerID` is equal to the `ID`.

The result should look like this,

```
ID  Employee    ManagerID
1   A           NULL
2   B           2
```

In essence no managers can be managers of managers.

At first I thought that it would be simple using a SELF Join and an `EXCLUDE` SQL statement however I cannot get this to work. I would prefer not to USE the `EXCLUDE` statement as my actual table has more columns and related data that I would like to return.

If you could help, I would be grateful.

Comment: I'm confused, please clarify.  What does 'non related ManagerIDs' mean? Are managers in the employee table (as one would expect)? If so, do they all have a ManagerID of NULL? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Correct, only Null and ID's that are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select employee, managerid
from your_table
where managerid is null 
or managerid = id
```